# Sylow p-subgroup of $GL_n(F_p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's the question:

Find a Sylow p-subgroup of $GL_n(F_p)$, and determine the number of Sylow p-subgroups.

So far here's what I've got:

- Order of $GL_n(F_p)$, which is $\prod_{j=1}^n p^n-p^{j-1}$ with j running from 1 to n,and thus the order of Sylow p-subgroup of it, and also its index.
- From the index, $\prod_{j=1}^n (p^{n-j+1}-1)$, we have the clue that the number of Sylow p-subgroups, s, both is congruent to 1 mod p and divides $\prod_{j=1}^n (p^{n-j+1}-1)$.

But this doesn't seem to carry me any further... Please help :(

Comment: Try to do this for $n=2$ first. Then for $n=3$. Then you'll see the pattern. (What is the order of the group, by the way?)

Comment: $\prod(P^n-P^(j-1))$, with j running from 1 to n

Comment: Edit the question and add that information there. (Also, notice that the numebr that you are claiming is the index is actually larger than the number you are claiming to be the order of the group!)

Comment: Oh write, sorry didn't notice that. Editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order of sylow p-subgroup is $p^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$,  a sylow p-subgroup would be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with diagonal entries 1

Comment: Literally just figured that out 4 seconds before reading this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: And the normalizer of that group is fairly easy to calculate.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Could you elaborate? I was just thinking about that too, it's pretty much the only way I can think of to calculate the number of Sylow p-subgroups (which are conjugates)

Comment: Edit: I think I got it. Is it the group of upper triangular matrices (with any kind of diagonal instead of all 1's)?

Comment: @benjamin  thats correct

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: To the bountier: this answer should get it; the answer is implicit in Benjamim's comment, where he characterizes the normalizer. Since all sylow p-subgroups are conjugate, their number is the index of the normalizer.